# How can I put a URL in a HTTP request (as the query string)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, http

I am building a webapp using Node and my server needs to be forwarded the API call that a user wants to make. Basically in the frontend the user enters the API call they want to make. A request should then be sent to the server with the details of that call.

What is the best way to send that information?

Comment: Could you encrypt it and send it as a parameter?
maybe base64?

Comment: How straightforward would that be?

Comment: When you put something on an url use **url encoding**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very simple example but let me know if you need more detail.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<script>
   function redirect(){
       //url you want to encrypt
       url = "http://www.test.com";
       //url encryption with BTOA function
       base64Url = btoa(url)
//       Lets Redirect to the new url with URL encrypted
       window.location = "http://www.newAddress.com?url="+base64Url
   }
</script>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="redirect()">redirect</a>
</body>
</html>
```

This will let you send the url trough the query string, in the other side you just get the string and decode it, it is base64 if you are using javascript you can use the function atob() to decode what we encode with btoa or any other base64 decoder if you are in other languages.

For more details you can check this page https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much :)